# How to recognize and perform operations on a Java table in a stand-alone Java application?

Tags: java, sikuli

Here is a scenario where in we have a Java stand-alone application with Java Tables in it. We are currently using Sikuli/Java to run few automations. Now, we need to right click on the rows populated in the Java Table one by one till I complete all the rows. Sikuli recognizes only images and, there are many fields which show common data in their respective columns. So, the screenshot logic will plausibly fail here. Looking for alternatives in Sikuli or Java or any other JAR.

Comment: welcome to SOF community. please read the help guide over  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Use your code samples, what you have tried so far and then mention your problem so the community can help you rather than opinion based questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact number of these rows/tables and you can iterate through them with your <kbd>TAB</kbd> button, you can try to simulate the same in Sikuli. If you need to check that the current row or cell is empty or has text in it you can do that with keyboard as well. For example you could simulate <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select the contents of the current cell and get them into your clipboard. Then you can just check if your clipboard has any text in it. You can find Sikuli clipboard related info [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Clipboard.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the lines in your table all start with a unique ID, you could use `App.getClipBoard()` to keep track of the lines your are working at.

```
type('c', KeyModifier.CTRL)
# Grab what is under the clipboard. 
textId = App.getClipboard()
print(textId)
```

If the previeus ID matched the new ID you are probebly at the last line.